# Reading content of a InMemoryRandomAccessStream into a Buffer using C++/WinRT

Tags: c++, windows, io, c++-winrt

I'm trying to serialise the content of an `winrt::Windows::UI::Input::Inking::InkStrokeContainer`. Microsoft provides the very convenient [ISF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/save-and-load-ink) format to do this.
Now I want to store the content of InkStrokeContainer into a `winrt::Windows::Storage::Streams::Buffer` object as follows:

```
// This code is running in a worker thread
using namespace winrt::Windows::Foundation;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Input;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Input::Inking;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Storage::Streams;


InkStrokeContainer inkContainer;

// Add some strokes to the inkContainer

InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream;
inkContainer.SaveAsync(stream, InkPersistenceFormat::Isf).get();

Buffer buffer(stream.Size());
stream.ReadAsync(buffer, buffer.Capacity(), InputStreamOptions::None).get();

std::cout << "Buffer size: " << buffer.Length() << "Stream size: " << stream.Size() << std::endl;
```

However, this code doesn't work and the output of the last line is always:

> Buffer size: 0 Stream size: 1102

It seems that nothing is being written into the buffer and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: `ReadAsync` is an asynchronous method. Please try to wait until it finishes by using the **co_await** keyword.

Comment: But I am calling .get() which means that the function will wait until it's finished and thus is no longer async, right?

Comment: Using `co_await` should be the general way to call an asynchronous method in C++-winrt. You can have a  try on this.

Comment: Does `co_await` work for you?